# Since MS ForeFront firewall is installed the network is going crazy

Tags: domain-name-system, firewall, microsoft-forefront

a few weeks ago we installed the new MS Forefront Firewall server.
Since that day we have trouble in our network.

example:
a user is trying to visit www.google.com -> his browser opens www.facebook.com

a user is trying to go to msdn.microsoft.com -> his browser tries to open msdn.facebook.com/...
This happens irregular. Its not easy to reproduce it.

Some of our users have reported that this kind of error happens much more when they try to visit SSL secured web sites (https://).

We already tried to analyze the log files of forefront firewall and our MS DNS server.
But no luck...

Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you have a Facebook related rule somewhat jacked up. Have you analyzed all of your firewall rules, specifically any dealing with facebook.com?

Comment: Especially a Web Chaining rule.

Comment: No there are no rules.

Answer (score 1):

If yuo are using forefront as a proxy the problem lies in the proxy ruies.  Examing the rulesets and you should discover the issue.

Comment: As far as I know we are not using the proxy.